# Can I stop my Lords from hating me?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

Every time I assign a fief, I get +20 with the lord I assign it to.

I also get -5 with every other lord.

Now given that I have 8 lords. If I assign everyone a fief, thats:

```
 20 - 5 - 5 - 5 - 5 - 5 - 5 - 5 = -15;
```

So basically my the more fiefs I capture the more I am hated. This is definately a flaw in the game.

I hear that having a family as your lords means it instead goes up for everyone. But lets be honest, its hard enough getting Lords on your side, Im sure not dropping all my existing and then trying to get more from scratch. Im at war, I need them.

Also, I guess I could assign all fiefs to one Lord til they hit 100, then move on to the next. But the negative I will gain with the lords would be huge. And could lead to them deserting.

I tried this TweakMB. It doesn't find the files. I select Floris 1.50. Im running Floris 1.53. How can I do it manually. I cant find the right info online.

Comment: It sounds like you're using a cheat or a trainer program?  It's hard to tell.  Could you clarify what you're looking for a bit more?

Comment: @fbueckert There are lots of txt files that can be modified in ways to alter the game. Like how much something scales; damage, money rewards etc. Im looking for how to modify the loss of reputation with Lords to be low or none existant when assigning fiefs only.

Comment: So are you asking for an in-game solution, or external?  Your question is implying both, but doesn't really specify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry. it would be external. The tweakMB.exe is suppose to load it all up into a GUI for you to make it simple. but I dont think it supports my version of Floris. But at the end of the day, I just want my lords to stop hating me for giving away fiefs - Any solution is fine by me.

Comment: I don't think tweakMB works with Floris 1.53 yet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In game, you can consult with all your lords before appointing a fief, then appoint the fief to the lord who has the most supporters amongst other lords. This should limit the negative relations hit to the lords who did not support the lord who eventually gets the fief.

Failing that you can modify your game using the module system to lessen the relationships hit. IF you're not familiar with modding the game and the module system this can be a bit of a challenge, but the way to do it is:

Find the file **module_scripts.py**, and look for the script **give_center_to_lord**.

Find the line:

```
(val_clamp, ":relation_with_liege_change", -5, 3)
```

This line signifies that the relationship change between lords and liege when awarding fiefs varies between -5 and 3. Change those values to whatever you like, for example -1, 20.

Note that this change will also affect other kings, so this makes getting their vassals harder.

To make the change only affect the player, change the line by this piece of code:

```
(try_begin),
(eq, ":faction_leader", "trp_player"),
(val_clamp, ":relation_with_liege_change", -5, 3), ##CHANGE THIS LINE HOWEVER YOU'D LIKE
(else_try),
(val_clamp, ":relation_with_liege_change", -5, 3), #THIS WILL BE FOR ALL OTHER KINGDOMS
(try_end)
```

Again, change the values in the above piece of code to whatever you want.

Source: [talewords forum](http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php?topic=215002.0).

Comment: While this looks like exactly what I want, I cannot find any python files (.py).  Also, in response to consulting lords. I tried that, but it means talking to every lord, in which case nearly all say, `I nominate myself`. And you cant change their minds. Plus I have to find them all and return back to my capital to assign it >.<  Do you know where the `.py` files are?

Comment: Sorry I was assuming you were familiar with the module system, which if you're not make my answer really confusing :). Basically it's the system trough which to mod the game available in the "other downloads" section on the official site: http://www.taleworlds.com/main.aspx?dir=download.aspx?type=2  Using that you can modify the game, an introduction is available here: http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php?topic=5408.0 .  Just as a heads up, if you're starting from scratch making the change you want will take considerable effort.

Comment: So the file doesnt exist currently on my machine ? :p Ive read about modifying them before, just never realised it took a lot of effort. I might just leave it then. And just try convincing them more often.

Comment: Correct, it doesn't exist on y our machine by default

Comment: I got so fed up, I just downloaded the needed modification stuff. But I also checked quickly to make sure Tweak MB wasnt updated. It says 22/6/12! Though states 2.50 Floris still. I gave it a whirl and this time it is reading! :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also wait till he is 'devoted' then try to recruit said lord, at that point he wont take any loyalty hit when you give the village to another lord. Alternativly, when you are recruiting for lords, be sure to tell them when they ask why they should join 'BECAUSE I WILL DEAL WITH ALL MEN FAIRLY'. This will lessen the amount of greedy lords that will come to your banner, and you're telling them starting off that you plan to deal with all lords equaly.

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to cheating, you make handle the issue by:

1. As it was already said, consulting lords on what do they think, and give the fief to the most popular lord lowers the penalty (or it should).
2. Hosting feasts frequently, it allows you to quickly restore the losses.
3. Obtaining good relationships with lords that you invite in advance, before they become your lords.
4. Probably limiting the amount of lords you have at the very beginning.

Yes, it is supposed to be hard to be a good ruler and maintain good relationships with everyone!